# simple login form using symfony

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, twig

This is my controller

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;   

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request,AuthenticationUtils $authUtils)
{
    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('blog/login.html.twig', array(
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
    ));
}
}
```

This is my security.yml

```
 providers:
    our_db_provider:
        entity:
            class: AppBundle:user
            property: uname

    in_memory:
        memory: 
            users:
                clement:
                  password: $2y$12$Z2B4JTnglzaYs4z73DBh9u/hIDN/E56CCrLKIjQxP6Q7aeLb5S6LO 
                  roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'
                admin:
                  password: symfony
                  roles: 'ROLES_ADMIN'
                ryan:
                  password: ryan1234
                  roles: 'ROLES_USER'


encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: 
          algorithm: bcrypt
          cost: 12
    AppBundle\Entity\User:
          algorithm: bcrypt    



firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false


    main:
        anonymous: ~
        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate
        http_basic: ~

        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html
        form_login: 
            login_path: login
            check_path: login


    secured_area:
        pattern: ^/
        provider: our_db_provider
        anonymous: ~
        logout: true

access_control:
    # require ROLE_ADMIN for /admin*
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

This is my view

```
<form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

{#
    If you want to control the URL the user
    is redirected to on success (more details below)
    <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account" />
#}

<button type="submit">login</button>
</form>
```

And I get this error.

> Controller "AppBundle\Controller\SecurityController::loginAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$authUtils" argument. Either the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this one.

Comment: You're using multiple firewalls, are you sure the correct one is used for the login form? `secured_area` does not have a login_form for example and matches `^/`.

Comment: I changed it to main now and still the same

Comment: The error message comes from the fact that $authUtils is not getting set.  Passing authUtils as an action argument is new to S3.3.  I suspect you are using an earlier version? Follow the 3.2 example instead: https://symfony.com/doc/3.2/security/form_login_setup.html  And yes your firewall does look unusual.

Comment: Yup you are right. I am using 3.2.
And I changed my firewall to main now thank you

Comment: Thank you for that

Answer (score 7):

This is not the correct answer to your question but a possible fix

1. change method signature to `public function loginAction(Request $request)`
2. add `$authUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');` at the beginning of your action

Answer (score 2):

If in Symfony 3.3 this feature is not working, you need to:

1. Enable Autowiring
2. Tag your controllers with `controller.service_arguments`

This is however default setting in symfony, so you only need to change it if you cleared/replaced [default services.yml](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/3.3/app/config/services.yml#L27-L30).

If you don't want to use autowire, you can explicitly [define argument types](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/controller.html#fetching-services-as-controller-arguments).

Comment: Friends of mine who are "SymfonyKillers" told me about that.. I did not understand because I was working on Symfony 3.1.

I've just upgrade...

Comment: I'm having this issue and I'm using Symfony 3.3.0.   Autowire is enabled and the controller is tagged.   Kind of weird as I thought this worked in all 3.3.x+ versions.  Oddly, in another project where I'm using 3.3.4, with the same code, it does work as expected.