# Symfony 4 AuthenticationUtils

Tags: php, authentication, service, symfony4

I am trying to create a user login with symfony 4 based on the tutorial from symfony.com.

I used the basic services.yaml file with the code below.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

```
public function loginAction(Request $request, \Twig_Environment $twigRenderer,AuthenticationUtils $authUtils)
{

    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authUtils->getLastUsername();


    return new response($twigRenderer->render('security/login.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error'         => $error,
        )
    ));
}
```

Errror:

Controller "App\Controller\SecurityController::loginAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$authUtils" argument. Either the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this one.

I don`t know how to solve this. Does someone have a suggestion?

Comment: I'm having the same issue on 4.0, and the two suggestions below didn't work.  I also tried to inject into the constructor (shouldn't matter), but same results.  Weird because I had the same issue when testing 3.4, but eventually got it to work.  Did these fixes work for you @Erik

Comment: They don't for me, also Symfony4.0, all 3 solutions dont work.

Answer (score 1):

I was with the same problem .. Try to run the command:

```
composer require security
```

Comment: There is no package security, you mean symfony/security? Anyway, that not work for me...

Answer (score 0):

add these to your services.yml to solve that error:

```
AppBundle\Controller\:
    resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
    public: true
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

check out this question:
[simple login form using symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346834/simple-login-form-using-symfony#44749768)

hope this help.

Comment: This just add's the controllers to the dependency injections. The issue here is, that `AuthenticationUtils` doesn't get injected. Probably because the security component (as @Guhh) suggested is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late, but still add here for other to refer.

Please add `autowire: true` to your controller service declaration. Symfony will automatically inject parameters of methods for you.

Comment: I'm new to symfony4.0, but I'm fairly certain you should not do this, they turned this explicitly *off* in this version. you shouldn't turn it on :) Fix the problem, don't hide it

Comment: @Martijn , you can check more on Symfony document, pls notice that we are talking about controller actions here (for the question)

Autowiring Controller Action Methods

If you're using the Symfony Framework, you can also autowire arguments to your controller action methods. This is a special case for autowiring, which exists for convenience. See Fetching Services for more details.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me (using Symfony 4.0) was to completely walk through the steps of the [Symfony security documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/security.html). Follow them all and chances are you'll get it working.

<sub>I am aware that we're not supposed the just share a link, but in this case there isn't a specific step to copy to this answer, do them all in order to get the proper result.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You must to check your services.yml file and make sure that your bundle is tagged. In my case, I got a bundle called AdminBundle and my services.yml seems like this:

```
AdminBundle\:
    resource: '../../src/AdminBundle/*'
    exclude: '../../src/AdminBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests}'

AdminBundle\Controller\:
    resource: '../../src/AdminBundle/Controller'
    public: true
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

Answer (score 0):

They key here is having your controller tagged with `controller.service_arguments`

So when registering controller service, you should have something similar:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    My\Namespace\Controller\LoginController:
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

Personally, I prefer to register all controllers at once, eg. like this:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: true

    controllers:
        resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/**/Application/Controller/*'
        namespace: 'My\Namespace\'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

Answer (score -2):

please do this it works for me

```
$authUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');
```